# Can't install cairo with cabal on Windows - how to get pkg-config on win?

Tags: haskell, cairo, cabal, pkg-config

```
Configuring cairo-0.12.0...
setup.exe: The program pkg-config version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not
be found.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cairo-0.12.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

so how can I get pkg-config on windows or how to install cairo then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the cairo development files installed?  Recall this isn't the same as having a cairo dll!  See the Windows section of their download page for [binaries](http://www.cairographics.org/download/).  Also, you can run `cabal install -v` for more verbosity in the error (which you should post if you're still stuck).

Comment: I'll try to make so, I though it was pkg-config trouble.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add "C:\Program Files\Gtk+\bin" enclosed in double quotes to PATH system variable so that pkg-config becomes visible to windows, you have to have the gtk+ installed first of course ...