# Is Yi buildable on Windows?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform, yi-editor

Is it possible to build the Haskell's [Yi](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yi) editor in Windows?

*UPDATE*: I fixed the [previous error](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9986817/1) by [installing cabal-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442588/install-cabal-dev-on-windows-7) but now the next one I get is:

```
C:\Data\yi> cabal-dev install -f-vty -fpango
...
Loading package cairo-0.12.4 ... cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to insta
ll:
yi-0.6.6.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

so I'm wandering is it even compatible with Windows?

My system spec:

1. Windows 8 64bit
2. Haskell Platform (GHC 7.4.2)
3. cabal-dev, [installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442588/install-cabal-dev-on-windows-7) from [github repo](https://github.com/creswick/cabal-dev) with:

   ```
   runhaskell -isrc admin/bootstrap
   ```
4. Gtk installed as per [wiki instructions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Gtk2Hs/Installation#Windows).

Comment: is this the same as, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336865/cant-install-cairo-with-cabal-on-windows-how-to-get-pkg-config-on-win

Comment: don't we have a [yi] tag yet?

Comment: There's gonna be some huge typo potential due to a PHP framework called `yii` -- how do you feel about `yi-editor` instead of just `yi`?

Answer (score 3):

The [HaskellWiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yi#Windows) says yes, as long as you install with `-f-vty -fpango`. It might be out of date, though; Yi development was dormant for a while.

As far as the error you get when trying to install glib, that doesn't have anything to do with Yi; you just need the `pkg-config` program to install Gtk2Hs (of which the glib package is a component). These resources might help you get Gtk2Hs installed:

- [HaskellWiki page about installing Gtk2Hs on Windows](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Gtk2Hs/Windows)
- [A blog post about the same](http://markshroyer.com/2010/10/gtk2hs-on-windows/) (circa 2010, so it might be a bit out of date)
- [Gtk2Hs' `INSTALL` file](http://code.haskell.org/gtk2hs/INSTALL)

Comment: I tried `-f-vty -fpango` - and that is the error I got. Anyways, I'll check out the resources and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you're missing gtk2hs on your machine. In the past Yi has been buildable on Windows, but it may not be easy.

Comment: I think I got gtk installed fine. I followed the wiki: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Gtk2Hs/Installation#Windows

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to clone the repository in a specific folder and start a manual install ?

I mean
1. Clone the repo with git or download the tarball on hackage.
2. Go to yi/yi (where the yi.cabal reside)
3. Do cabal configure
4. If previous failed, then as the ouput will say, Install the required dependency with the expected version (cabal install Diff-0.2.0 ...).
5. do cabal build (to compile), set the highest verbose mode (it should be [possible](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-latest/doc/API/Cabal/Distribution-Verbosity.html))
6. Anyway even it's not compiling, we should have a better error log.

Side note, n yi.cabal, line 16,
**tested-with: GHC==7.0.2, GHC==7.4.1, GHC==7.6.1**
May be, it's a good occasion to update to 7.6.1.