# install vacuum-cairo on win7 64bit

Tags: haskell, cabal, cairo, vacuum

I am relatively new to Haskell and never installed a package before and I can't figure out how to fix this thing.
So this is what I did: 
- I installed Haskell Platform
- I tried to run "cabal install vacuum-cairo"

And this is what i get (the last few lines that seemed important):

```
setup.exe: The program pkg-config version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not
be found.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cairo-0.12.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
gio-0.12.4 depends on glib-0.12.4 which failed to install.
glib-0.12.4 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
gtk-0.12.4 depends on glib-0.12.4 which failed to install.
pango-0.12.4 depends on glib-0.12.4 which failed to install.
svgcairo-0.12.1.1 depends on glib-0.12.4 which failed to install.
vacuum-cairo-0.5 depends on glib-0.12.4 which failed to install.
```

I've also tried some things then that I read on the internet but nothing worked and I really didn't find that much.
Could someone help me fixing this? I'd really like to use that package to get a better clue of what I'm doing in Haskell :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336865/cant-install-cairo-with-cabal-on-windows-how-to-get-pkg-config-on-win.